# Etymology of the phrase "cannot see the forest for the trees"

Tags: etymology, idioms, prepositions

How did this phrase originate grammatically? I’m especially interested in the fragment “for the trees”.

See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_forest_for_the_trees for its definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English, this saying goes back at least to the 16th century:

> 1546 J. HEYWOOD Prov. II. iv. (1867) 51 *Plentie is nodeintie, ye see not your owne ease. I see, ye can not see the wood for trees.* —*Oxford English Dictionary*

This is *for* in the sense of “on account of”, “because of”, which goes back as far as Old English. (“[for](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=for)”, *Online Etymology Dictionary*)

You can read the saying as:

> Cannot see the forest *because of* the trees.

Comment: I'm skeptical about the *because of* interpretation. Good citations?

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for?q=for Sense 5 "Having [the thing mentioned] as a reason or cause". Bear in mind that this is an idiomatic expression at least 450 years old.

Comment: @Kris I must say that I'm a little surprised that people are not familiar with the "because of" meaning of "for"; to me the meaning of the idiom is completely transparent.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Lol -- it's not that people are *not familiar* (one must avoid making this error of judgment) -- *transparency* is subjective.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That citation says nothing about the idiom. My comment is awaiting response from MετάEd. Wait.

Comment: @Kris Do you mean you are skeptical that "for" can ever be interpreted as "on account of/because of", or just in the OP's phrase? If the latter, what do you think the phrase means?

Comment: Just in the OP's phrase. '*for*' can of course be interpreted as '*on account of*' / '*because of*'.

Comment: @Kris *If the latter, what do you think the phrase means*?

Comment: from http://home.comcast.net/~modean52/oeme_dictionaries.htm: `for [] 1. prep w.i.d.a.; w.d.a. (local) before, in the sight of, in or into the presence of, as far as;`

Comment: @MετάEd While I understand that you end up with the correct meaning if you swap in "because of" in place of "for", I'm not convinced of the etymology.

Comment: @MarkBeadles How can the meaning of an idiom be "transparent"?

Comment: @self By the way, the dictionary quote was from some unlabeled Old English dictionary (too late to edit previous comment).

Comment: @HikeDanakian I simply mean that "cannot see the forest on account of the trees" (my natural reading of the phrase) is the meaning that to me is **obvious and can be derived directly from the meaning of its constituent parts**. I realize that transparency is a personal thing. It seems evident from this discussion that some people regard the phrase as truly idiomatic, with a "frozen" meaning that is no longer clear from looking at its parts. My statement above was that I was surprised (genuinely, not rhetorically) that this is the case.

Comment: Also, @HikeDanakian The Old English meaning is not relevant here; 1546 is early Modern English.

Comment: @Kris The usage isn't confined to this phrase. We still fine and imprison people *for* their offenses, we still do other things *for* various reasons, and after all that we still can't win *for* losing.

Comment: ‘Because of/on account of’ is definitely the overarching meaning here, but to me, _for_ in this context specifically indicates an obstacle that is in the way. _Because of/on account of_ are vaguer in their denotation of how and why they indicate the cause of something; _for_ is only substitutable with certain of these hows and whys, of which ‘obstacle blocking the path’ is one.

Answer (score -1):

This idiom is ambiguous for the "for"... (cough cough)

If "for" means "because of", then the trees, aka details, ironically muddle the overall picture of the forest, aka the main idea.

However, if for means "in place of; instead of", then it's similar to the idiom  "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink."  So, you can't see the forest on behalf of the trees.

In other words, you can't comprehend a problem on behalf of the ones who are part of that problem.